# A polynomial with its coefficients in principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ be an integral domain and $a\in A$. Define $I$ be the set of
> polynomials $f(X)\in A[X]$ such that all the coefficients are in the
> principal ideal $aA$. Prove that  $I$ is the prime ideal of $A[X]$ if
> and only if $aA$ is the prime ideal of $A$.

I have proved that $I$ is the principal ideal of the ring $A[X]$, particularly $I=aA[X]$. Could anyone continue this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question about prime ideals, and the question about principal ideals are quite different. Let's take them 1 at a time:

$\textbf{I is a principal ideal generated by a:}$
Assume that $f=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ is a polynomial in $I$. Then each coefficient, $a_k$ can be written as $ar_k$. Then by distributivity $f=a(r_nx^n+...+r_0)$, which shows that $f$ is an element of $aA[x]$, so $I\subseteq aA[x]$. Using distributivity similarly also shows that $aA[x]\subseteq I$, so the sets are equal.\

$\textbf{$aA$ is a prime ideal in $A$ if $I$ is a prime ideal in $A[x]$}$
Assume $r,s\in A$ and $rs\in aA$. Then we also have $r,s\in A[x]$ and $rs\in I$ with, $r,s$ and $rs$ being constant polynomials. By our assumption, $r$ or $s$ must be in $I$. As both $r$ and $s$ are constants, we conclude that one of them must be in $aA$.

$\textbf{I is a prime ideal in $A[x]$ if $aA$ is prime in $A$}$
The fastest way to do this is probably just to notice that $A[X]/I\cong(A/aA)[x]$. By assumption $aA$ is a prime ideal, so $A/aA$ is an integral domain. Hence $(A/aA)[x]$ is an integral domain. So $A[X]/I$ is an integral domain, which is equivalent to $I$ being a prime ideal in $A[x]$.
If you haven't seen it before, the isomorphism can be obtained through the homomorphism $A[x]\rightarrow  (A/aA)[x]$, $a_nx^n+...+a_0\mapsto [a_n]_I x^n+...+[a_0]_I$. This is surjective and has kernel $I$. So the First Isomorphism Theorem gives us the desired isomorphism.
Alternatively, you can notice that if $fg\in I$ for $f,g$ polynomials, then one of them must have leading coefficient in $aA$, by our assumption, and then you can work 'downwards' to show that all the coefficents must be in $aA$ - or you could do a similar strategy working 'upwards'